# writing csv from Groupby with whole data and new columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, multiple-columns

**The Situation:**

I grouped my dataframe data and did some aggregation. When I'm printing, I get correct data, but while writing it into CSV file, I am getting only 3 columns coming in CSV which is in aggregation part.

Also I want to add one more column named `AVG` which will come from deviation:

```
AMOUNT/CUST_NUMB
```

**My code:**

```py
final=pd.DataFrame(gg.groupby(['Phone','BID', 'P_NAME',
                'STATE','VILLAGE', 'TALUK', 'DISTRICT'])
    .agg({'AMOUNT':'sum', 'CUST_NUMB': 'count','DATE': 'max'}))
     
final.to_csv("spend.csv",index=False)
```

[OUTPUT I AM GETTING FROM MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI1Ov.png)

**The Question:**

So i want to write whole DF in one CSV with that extra column named :

```
avg_spend
```

Please could you help me with this.

Comment: Please provide code where you write to csv. And what are those: Trans_count/Total_amt?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one:

```
final.to_csv("spend.csv")
```

If this is not what you expect please provide more details

Comment: Yes it worked i have to remove index= false
but avg_spend also i want to add in that which i was not able to add because
AMOUNT/CUST_NUMB are already in aggr part where it was giving an error

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal demo reproducing your problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Phone': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'BID': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'P_NAME': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'STATE': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'VILLAGE': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'TALUK': ['1', '2', '1'],
    'DISTRICT': ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'AMOUNT': [3, 4, 5],
    'CUST_NUMB': ['12', '13', '14'],
    'DATE': ['20211025', '20211025', '20211025']
}
gg = pd.DataFrame(data)
final = pd.DataFrame(gg.groupby(['Phone', 'BID', 'P_NAME',
                                 'STATE', 'VILLAGE', 'TALUK', 'DISTRICT'])
                     .agg({'AMOUNT': 'sum', 'CUST_NUMB': 'count', 'DATE': 'max'}))
print(final)
#                                                AMOUNT  CUST_NUMB      DATE
# Phone BID P_NAME STATE VILLAGE TALUK DISTRICT                             
# x     x   x      x     x       1     x              8          2  20211025
#                                2     x              4          1  20211025
```

Use `reset_index()` to convert the groups to columns:

```py
final = final.reset_index()
print(final)
#   Phone BID P_NAME STATE VILLAGE TALUK DISTRICT  AMOUNT  CUST_NUMB      DATE
# 0     x   x      x     x       x     1        x       8          2  20211025
# 1     x   x      x     x       x     2        x       4          1  20211025
```

Add new column `avg_spend` and write in `CSV`:

```py
final['avg_spend'] = final['AMOUNT'] / final['CUST_NUMB']
print(final)
#   Phone BID P_NAME STATE  ... AMOUNT CUST_NUMB      DATE  avg_spend
# 0     x   x      x     x  ...      8         2  20211025        4.0
# 1     x   x      x     x  ...      4         1  20211025        4.0

final.to_csv("spend.csv", index=False)
```